# Enum toString sometimes replacing i with ı

Tags: java, android, google-analytics

I recently got a report that a few Google Analytics event category names were being recorded with an i character with out a dot on top.

> Pageviews and events occurring twice, once without dots over the i.

I had to look to believe it. Sure enough, I had an event called favorite and there was a handful called favorıte. Copy and paste that weird character into a terminal or a monospace font just to see how weird it is. `favorıte`

My first suspicion is my code where I generate the strings for the category names using `toString` on an enum.

```
public enum AnalyticsEvent {

    SCREEN_VIEW,
    FAVORITE,
    UN_FAVORITE,
    CLICK_EVENT,
    ... reduced for brevity;

    public String val() {
        return this.toString().toLowerCase();
    }
}
```

Example of how that enum is used:

```
@Override
public void logSearchTag(String type, String value) {
    ...
    logGAEvent(AnalyticsEvent.SEARCH_TAG.val(), type, value);
}

private void logGAEvent(String category, String action, String label) {
    ... // mGATracker = instance of com.google.android.gms.analytics.Tracker;
            mGATracker.send(addCustomDimensions(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder()
                    .setCategory(category)
                    .setAction(action)
                    .setLabel(label))
                    .build());
    ...
}
```

I am going to solve this by actually assigning a string to the enums and instead return that in the `val()` function.

Though, I am curious if anyone knows why on a small handful of devices `Enum.toString` returns the enum name with that weird character replacing the i. I mean small. 8 out 50,000 is the average. Or is it possible that assumption is wrong and the error is on analytics service end somewhere? Really highly doubt that.

Comment: Best practice Android is to use constants instead of ENUM.

Comment: Yes, I know. Don't worry that code base is not littered with ENUMs. That is the only place they were used. Makes very little difference if it is an ENUM or constant there regardless.

Comment: Nope  now  that ENUM is in your code the ENUM routines have to be used to execute it.  Constants are just there in the byte code.

Comment: You are preaching to the choir. I know this already. I am not saying it is better performing, just that I am willing to take that tiny performance hit there. It is not the end of the world. I am very aware of the differences of ENUMs and constants.

Comment: @danny117 No hard feelings, totally agree this question needs down-voting ( it's bad ). It was a momentary lapse of duh for me. But please read this, it is some food for thought for you. https://twitter.com/jakewharton/status/551876948469620737?lang=en Help you open your mind a little.

Comment: He has 32K more follwers than then seven danny117 does on twitter too.

Comment: I have 68 followers on twitter!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `String#toLowerCase` method uses the default locale of the system. This use locale specific characters such as `ı` instead of `i`. In order to fix this problem call `toLowerCase` with a locale:

```
String test = "testString";
test.toLowerCase(java.util.Locale.ENGLISH) // Or your preferred locale
```

Comment: Thanks! I'd accidentally turned off the lint for that in studio at some other point in time. When I alt-enter tried to fix another lowercase but chose wrong option accidentally turning the inspection off. :/ Funny how I didn't notice it with out lint and looked in completely wrong place for problem.